# Development Provisioning Profile

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

Do I need `.mobileprovision` file for uploading app signed with Development Provisioning Profile for devices via iTunes?

I removed all profiles in device and I'm trying to upload app without Provisioning Profile. But finally this profile is appearing in Xcode Organizer.

I'd like to make sure that another guys can use app without Provisioning Profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, let me clarify, for distributing apps not signed with Enterprise In-house distribution profile it is mandatory that device UDIDs be included in the `.mobileprovision` used to sign the binary package. Without including UDIDs the app will not install on the device. Since you are using development profile you need to include device UDIDs of all your friends who wish to install your app.

If I am understanding your question correctly, I think you should create a signed `.ipa`(archive) file rather than a signed `.app` for distributing it to your friends. `.ipa` file contains an embedded provisioning file within and will install it on the device while application is getting installed. If you distribute the `.app` you will also need to send the `.mobileprovision` along with it so that your friend can install it on his device.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

No it's not posssible if you want to upload app on appstore you need provisoning profile or if you want to test on real device it's needed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need provisioning profiles and iOS developer certificate, iOS distribution certificate and make sure that provisioning profiles are green marked in organizer and also these certificates exist in keychain.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to upload app without provisioning file.For testing purpose there is a way.But You need to provision the app for submitting.
Please follow this link for testing If You require.
http://mhassan.me/2013/02/15/using-xcode-without-provisioning-profile/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test your app on device, you will need to register the UDID of the device with the development provisioning profile and then code sign using that updated provisioning profile.